# How do I prove a set is not simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, homology-cohomology

The set in question is the unit open disc $U$ with the origin omitted. I know that this set is not simply connected as the path, say the circle centred at the origin with a radius of 1/2 is not homotopic to any point in $U$. However, how do I mathematically express this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this can be adapted https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1654655/399263

Comment: @zwim thanks for the link. Sadly, I am encountaring this in Complex Analysis and the theorems that the answers in that link are using I have simply not met. If it is of any help, I am following Serge Lang's Introduction to Complex Analysis at a graduate level

Comment: What characterizations of “simply connected” do you know? It is “easy” to show that the complement is not connected, or that Cauchy's integral theorem does not hold in the punctured disk.

Comment: Hi @MartinR, I believe Cauchy's theorem has been adapted to homtopy so far in book, so yes it is something I can use. However, I have never used it in this context. Any idea as how to proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a simply connected domain $D \subset \Bbb C$ is $\oint_\gamma f(z) \, dz = 0$ for all functions $f$ holomorphic in $D$ and all (rectifiable) closed curves $\gamma$ in $D$. That is because the integral is invariant under the homotopy which transforms $\gamma$ to a single point. (See also  [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)).

But for $D = \{ z \mid 0 < |z| < 1 \}$ we have
$$ 
\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \oint_{|z| = 1/2} \frac{dz}{z} = 1 \ne 0
$$
as you can calculate easily. The integral is in fact the [winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number) of the circle with radius $1/2$ with respect to the point zero.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I have added Caychy's integral theorem to my notes and I have proved it myself as the proof follows from previous theorems (I wonder why Lang didn't write it explicitly?). Just a quick question, could you explain what you meant by taking the "complement is not connected" approach?

Comment: @MathsWizzard: A connected  open set $D \subset \Bbb C $ is simply connected iff its complement is connected. Here the complement has two components: The point at the origin and the unbounded component $\{ |z| \ge 1 \}$.